# For each loop: Java

Tags: java, loops

I understand that this step requires a for each loop, but how would i go about writing one suited to this situation?

```
  >Move every fragment in the collage by a given amount.
  >@param xDelta int pixels of horizontal move
  >@param yDelta int pixels of vertical move

public void move(int xDelta, int yDelta)
{
    for

}
```

Comment: What element are you iterating over? List of elements? a Set? You could take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for:

```
public void move(final int xDelta, final int yDelta) {
    for (Point p : points) {
        p.setX(p.getX() + xDelta);
        p.setY(p.getY() + yDelta);
    }
}
```

*Assuming that you have a `Collection` of your class that contains an x and a y value*. E.g. one of the following:*

- `List<Point> points = new LinkedList<>();` or
- `Set<Point> points = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Collection` of elements to iterate over, such as `ArrayList`. Therefore if you want to do this using *foreach* loop, you first need to implement a class to hold fragments, then make a list of them, e.g. `ArrayList<Fragment>` and finally iterate over the list, such as this

```
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentsList) {
    // do the moving
}
```